# Join JSON Object member string values together

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

```
"category": [{
      "id": 28,
      "name": "Dogs"
  },
  {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "Cats"
  },
  {
      "id": 878,
      "name": "Sheep"
  }],
```

I have the above JSON parsed (using .ajax and jsonp as callback) and I would like to join all the values of "name" into a string. i.e. "Dogs, Cats, Sheep". How can I do this? I have tried simple join on "category" and name, i.e.

```
var cats = categories.join(", ");
```

OR

```
var cats = categories.name.join(", ");
```

But since we are looking at it's members and their string values, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This looks like a job for `$.map`!

```
var data = {
    "category": [{
          "id": 28,
          "name": "Dogs"
      },
      {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "Cats"
      },
      {
          "id": 878,
          "name": "Sheep"
      }]
}

var cats = $.map(data.category, function(v){
    return v.name;
}).join(', ');
```

Comment: Thanks, your response helped me. I used the abbreviated syntax: `$.map(data.category, (v)=>{return v.name}).join(', ');`

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = "";
for(var i=0; category.length; i++)
{
   text += category[i].name;
   if(i!=category.length-1)
       text += ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler, shorter version:

```js
const category = [{
      "id": 28,
      "name": "Dogs"
  },
  {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "Cats"
  },
  {
      "id": 878,
      "name": "Sheep"
  }]
```

```
let cats = category.map((item) => {
             return item.name;
           }).join(", ");
```

On the first part, the map function will return a string array with the contents `item.name`.

```js
[ "Dogs", "Cats", "Sheep" ]
```

Since on arrays we have the ability to call `join` that will put all the items in array together but separated by whatever we pass to the `join` (in this case we have `", "` it will separate by a comma and a space)

In the end we have:

```
Dogs, Cats, Sheep
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your code

Comment: This is definitely better than the accepted answer.