# Create a custom variable in Thymeleaf that is used in Javascript

Tags: thymeleaf, local-variables, inline-code

My object returned is a list like this:

```
data = [{'phone': '321-321-321',
          'email': 'test@test.com'
         },
        {'phone' : '123-123-123', 
         'email': 'bc@bcc.com'
        }]
```

I need a custom variable to be used in Javascript that looks like this (in fact a localstorage variable): 
//Javascript variable needs to iterate over the data and create a comma seperated list:

```
//var emails = 'test@test.com, bc@bcc.com'
```

Is there any way of doing this efficiently?

Comment: You need to do it on server side or on client side? It's not clear from your question. If `data` is a `javascript` variable you can do it like [in this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043865/join-json-object-member-string-values-together).  Otherwise you can do the same operation on server side, then send it to `Thymeleaf`.

Comment: Client side in this case. Though the ideal solution would be server side, but that is not feasible at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but you can assign Spring object to javascript variable like this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
...

var username = /*[[${session.user.name}]]*/ 'Sebastian';

...
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

[documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart)

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in dom using

```
<div style="display: none" id="data" th:data-form-data="${formData}"></div>
//Access using document.querySelector("#id").dataset
```